# Where Grails set defaults errors in server side

Tags: spring, grails

I've got 2 domain classes Form and FormItem. Form has many FormItems. I've tried to run my grails application with 3 items in form, and obviously set wrong value one of my fields in first item. After clicking "submit" I recieved 2 error messages instead of one.  It's same error message "Property No. of packages with value -9 is less than minimum value 0". Here is my questions.
Where is Grails trying to set  error messages by default and why 2 error instead of one (It's not a specific to my task, I try in various projects and got 2 messages instead of one) ?

**EDITED**
Errors displayed in this way.

```
<g:eachError>
        <dt>
          <a href=""
                   onclick="alert('adas'); javascript:document.getElementById('${it.getProperties().get("field")}').focus();
                   return false;">
                    <g:message error="${it}"/>
                </a>
            </dt>
</g:eachError>

//FormController    
def submit() {
        def formX = mergeGetFromSession()
        formX.status = "Stored"
        FormX.withTransaction {
            if (formX.save(flush: true)) {
                formXTaskService.startProcess(formX)
            }
        }

        if (formX.hasErrors()) {
            formX.isDocumentEditable = true
            render(view: "create", model: [formXInstance: formX])
        } else {
            session.invalidate()
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'formX.label', default: 'FormX'), formX.id])
            redirect(action: "show", id: formX.id)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where / how are you displaying your errors?

Answer (score 0):

It's stored at `grails-app/i18n/messages.properties`

See also http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#validationAndInternationalization

Comment: I know that it's stored at message.properties, I want to know where grails try to set error in server side.

Comment: please look at my edited code, and pls explain where is error setter. :)

Comment: must be at `formX.save(..)` line